# Not able to install Windows 8 on desktop PC

Tags: windows-8-preview, windows-installation

I can't install Windows 8 on my Asus 945G motherboard, dual core 2.0, 2GB DDR2 RAM system.

I think it is 64-bit. I have Windows 7 32-bit installed. While installing from CD it says

> some CD/DVD drivers required by system are missing

The same message comes when installing from a pen drive. WEI says my PC system is 64-bit capable though.

Comment: Can you provide some more information on your processor? AND, did you buy this computer from a retailer with 32 bit installed? If so, it most likely does not support 64 bit... so your processor would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the contents of the DVD (it's not a CD) to your hard drive, then install it from there.

Also, possibly check your system's BIOS and make sure that the CPU has [64-bit features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EM64T).

Comment: Gibson Research's SecurAble.exe is saying 
Intel Pentium Dual CPU E2180 @2.00 GHz is 
64 Maximum Bit Length.

is that enough of some other component has to be 64-bit before a 64-bit os can be installed?

Comment: @user158509 Yes, it's 64-bit according to this: http://ark.intel.com/products/31733 - however, there's still a question (I did a search) about whether or not it can run, so I found this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions which has very specific instructions on how to tell whether or not you can run 64-bit windows. Good luck!